# Problema com o Union no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta e está dando o seguinte erro:

> Unknown column 'FILIAL' in 'field list'

A consulta é a seguinte:

```
SELECT TICKET, DATAHORA, TIPO, ESTADO, CRITICIDADE, LOGIN, PARECER, INFOPEND, PROP, DATAPROP, PREV, SRD, PROT, REAB,FILIAL
FROM (
SELECT 
      TC.TN TICKET, TC.CREATE_TIME DATAHORA,  TT.NAME TIPO, TS.NAME ESTADO, TP.NAME CRITICIDADE, US.LOGIN LOGIN,
      CASE  
        WHEN TH.NAME LIKE  '%PARECER%' THEN RIGHT(TH.NAME, POSITION('%' IN REVERSE(TH.NAME))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END PARECER,
      CASE  
        WHEN TH.NAME LIKE  '%INFORMACOESPENDENTES%' THEN RIGHT(TH.NAME, POSITION('%' IN REVERSE(TH.NAME))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END INFOPEND,
      CASE  
        WHEN AR.A_SUBJECT LIKE  '%ATUALIZAÇÃO PROPRIETÁRIO%' THEN LEFT(AR.A_FROM, POSITION('<' IN (AR.A_FROM))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END PROP,
      CASE  
        WHEN AR.A_SUBJECT LIKE  '%ATUALIZAÇÃO PROPRIETÁRIO%' THEN (AR.CREATE_TIME)
        ELSE ''
        END DATAPROP,
      CASE  
        WHEN TH.NAME LIKE  '%PREVISAOATENDIMENTO%' THEN RIGHT(TH.NAME, POSITION('%' IN REVERSE(TH.NAME))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END PREV,
      CASE  
        WHEN TH.NAME LIKE  '%SRD%' THEN RIGHT(TH.NAME, POSITION('%' IN REVERSE(TH.NAME))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END SRD,
      CASE  
        WHEN TH.NAME LIKE  '%PROTOCOLO%' THEN RIGHT(TH.NAME, POSITION('%' IN REVERSE(TH.NAME))-1)
        ELSE ''
        END PROT,
      CASE  
        WHEN TS.NAME LIKE  '%REABERTO' THEN (TS.NAME)
        ELSE ''
        END REAB

   FROM OTRS2.TICKET TC
   INNER JOIN OTRS2.TICKET_TYPE TT ON TC.TYPE_ID = TT.ID
   INNER JOIN OTRS2.TICKET_STATE TS ON TC.TICKET_STATE_ID = TS.ID
   INNER JOIN OTRS2.TICKET_PRIORITY TP ON TC.TICKET_PRIORITY_ID=TP.ID
   INNER JOIN OTRS2.USERS US ON TC.CREATE_BY=US.ID
   INNER JOIN OTRS2.TICKET_HISTORY TH ON TC.ID=TH.TICKET_ID 
   INNER JOIN OTRS2.ARTICLE AR ON TC.ID=AR.TICKET_ID
   UNION 
        SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CUSTOMER.LOGIN FILIAL FROM OTRS2.CUSTOMER_USER CUSTOMER
 ) A
```

PS: Até eu colocar o `UNION`, a *query* estava funcionando direitinho e retornando os resultados.

Comment: Os dois selects tem um número diferente de colunas. Como é um UNION os dois, tem que ter a mesma quantidade de colunas... não tem como algumas linhas terem x colunas e outras terem y...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É exatamente o que está falando na mensagem, os selects precisam ter o mesmo número de colunas.

No caso você tentou trazer apenas a última coluna `FILIAL` no último select com a tabela `OTRS2.CUSTOMER_USER`.

Para possível solução, você tem que preencher os campos com valores padrão para as outras colunas que não estão na tabela `OTRS2.CUSTOMER_USER`. E inclusive, preencher um valor padrão para a coluna `FILIAL` nos outros selects.

No exemplo abaixo, considere o `CAMPO_4` como seu campo `FILIAL`:

```
select CAMPO_1, CAMPO_2, CAMPO_3, null as CAMPO_4
  from TABELA_1
 union
select null as CAMPO_1, null as CAMPO_2, null as CAMPO_3, CAMPO_4
  from TABELA_2
```

Comment: Eu tentei fazer o que vc explicou e editei a query da pergunta, porém agora ele não reconhece o campo da tabela.

Answer (score -1):

Estava faltando colocar null filial no primeiro select e dar os alias a cada uns dos nulls do segundo select! 
Obrigada aos que me ajudaram!

Comment: Olá! Poderia detalhar melhor a resposta final para sua dúvida? Não entendi bem como foi a sua solução.